# right way to get sum of all the counts done in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum

This is my query, I want to get how many numbers of phones call received today as one column, so how do I do a sum using count function?

```
SELECT (uniquecallerID), [Callername]
FROM [dbo].[phonedatabase] (nolock)
WHERE calltime BETWEEN '2020-08-23' AND '2020-08-24'
-- GROUP BY whatever
```

If I do a sum, that would just return the total sum? how do I return the total numbers of all calls received today, I would do count `uniquecallerID` and then put them into sum. How do I do that?

Sample data:

```
UniqueID    callername
----------------------
2619        Jack
2358        Travie
2359        Travis S
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `count(distinct)`?  Assuming that `uniqueCallerID` identifies what you want to count:

```
select  count(distinct uniquecallerID)
from [dbo].[phonedatabase] (nolock)
where calltime >= '2020-08-23' and
      calltime < '2020-08-24'
```